# Getting 'undefined method `merge!' when merging SoundCloud exchange token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, authentication, soundcloud

I'm working on an app that interacts with SoundCloud and I'm having an issue when I try to save the exchange_token that I'm getting back from the server (among other things) and I *really* could use some assistance.

According to the error I'm getting:

```
undefined method `merge!' for nil:NilClass
```

The problem apparently lies with line 10 in my sclouds_controller.rb file (included below):

```
soundcloud_client.exchange_token(:code => params[:code])
```

Which is calling a method in the SoundCloud gem that I'm using. Here's the line in the SoundCloud gem that the error originates from:

```
params.merge!(client_params)
```

That can be found on line 23 of the following method (taken from the client.rb file in the SoundCloud gem):

```
def exchange_token(options={})
  store_options(options)
  raise ArgumentError, 'client_id and client_secret is required to retrieve an access_token' if client_id.nil? || client_secret.nil?
  client_params = {:client_id => client_id, :client_secret => client_secret}
  params = if options_for_refresh_flow_present?
    {
      :grant_type => 'refresh_token',
      :refresh_token => refresh_token,
    }
  elsif options_for_credentials_flow_present?
    {
      :grant_type => 'password',
      :username => @options[:username],
      :password => @options[:password],
    }
  elsif options_for_code_flow_present?
    {
      :grant_type => 'authorization_code',
      :redirect_uri => @options[:redirect_uri],
      :code => @options[:code],
    }
  end
  params.merge!(client_params)
  response = handle_response(false) {
    self.class.post("https://#{api_host}#{TOKEN_PATH}", :query => params)
  }
  @options.merge!(:access_token => response.access_token, :refresh_token => response.refresh_token)
  @options[:expires_at] = Time.now + response.expires_in if response.expires_in
  @options[:on_exchange_token].call(*[(self if @options[:on_exchange_token].arity == 1)].compact)
  response
end
```

However, if I throw a 'raise' in my sclouds_controller.rb file like this:

```
def connected
  if params[:error].nil?
    raise
    soundcloud_client.exchange_token(:code => params[:code])
```

Then, in the console, manually paste in the following line:

```
soundcloud_client.exchange_token(:code => params[:code])
```

I get back the following response (which, to me, appears to be successful):

```
$ #<SoundCloud::HashResponseWrapper access_token="xxxxx" expires_in=21599 refresh_token="xxxxx" scope="*">
```

Any idea why this is happening? I'm trying to learn what I'm doing wrong, especially since I'm not sure if I'm going about this in the right way. Here's some of my code for a little more context. Thanks in advance!

### sclouds_controller.rb:

```
class ScloudsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:connect, :connected]

def connect
  redirect_to soundcloud_client.authorize_url(:display => "popup")
end

def connected
  if params[:error].nil?
    soundcloud_client.exchange_token(:code => params[:code])

    unless user_signed_in?
      flash[:alert] = 's'
      redirect_to :login
    end

    current_user.update_attributes!({
       :soundcloud_access_token => soundcloud_client.access_token,
      :soundcloud_refresh_token => soundcloud_client.refresh_token,
         :soundcloud_expires_at => soundcloud_client.expires_at
    })
  end

  redirect_to soundcloud_client.redirect_uri
end

def disconnect
  login_as nil
  redirect_to root_path
end

private
  def soundcloud_client
  return @soundcloud_client if @soundcloud_client

  @soundcloud_client = User.soundcloud_client(:redirect_uri  => 'http://localhost:3000/sclouds/connected/')
  end
end
```

### user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

attr_accessor :soundcloud_access_token, :soundcloud_refresh_token, :soundcloud_expires_at

has_one :scloud

      @SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxx'
  @SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxx'
              @REDIRECT_URI = 'xxxxx'

  def self.soundcloud_client(options={})
    options = {
          :client_id => @SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID,
      :client_secret => @SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_SECRET,
       :redirect_uri => @REDIRECT_URI
    }.merge(options)

    Soundcloud.new(options)
  end

  def soundcloud_client(options={})
    client = self.class.soundcloud_client(options)

    options= {
      :access_token  => soundcloud_access_token,
      :refresh_token => soundcloud_refresh_token,
      :expires_at    => soundcloud_expires_at
    }.merge(options)

    client.on_exchange_token do
      self.update_attributes!({
        :soundcloud_access_token  => client.access_token,
        :soundcloud_refresh_token => client.refresh_token,
        :soundcloud_expires_at    => client.expires_at
      })
    end

    client
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error message and on which line it happens? At the moment your question boils down to "find the bug in this code and fix it for me", which is pretty rude. By the way, I don't see any use of `merge!` in the code provided.

Comment: Hey @Mischa, thanks for responding so quickly. Sorry for the way the question was originally worded - I've no intentions of being rude. I spent quite a few hours Googling possible solutions and reworking my code, but to no avail, so I've just reached a point of desperation. I've made some edits to my question that will hopefully add some more context to the question for you. Thanks!

Comment: It's much better now, but still unclear where the error comes from exactly. Could you also show the line that errors in the SoundCloud library that you are apparently using.

Comment: You're having `attr_accessor :soundcloud_access_token, :soundcloud_refresh_token, :soundcloud_expires_at`, but later your doing `update_attributes({:soundcloud_access_token => ...})`, which suggests they are fields in your `users` table. If they are fields in your `users` table, you don't need `attr_accessor`.

Comment: @Mischa, I've edited my post and added the code from the SoundCloud gem itself that is the actual source of the error. Apologies for the ambiguity (this is the first question I've asked on SO, so I appreciate your patience). Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks strange to me. Could you answer my question about `attr_accessor` above? Also constants in Ruby don't start with an `@` generally. I'd use `SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID` instead of `@SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

```
options= {
      :access_token  => soundcloud_access_token,
      :refresh_token => soundcloud_refresh_token,
      :expires_at    => soundcloud_expires_at
    }.merge(options)
```

How does this work?

You're trying to set the `options` local var (which is a duplicate of the `options` argument in your method), and then you're trying to merge `options`? Looks like a self-referential loop to me...

---

**Method**

Secondly, you mention the error is caused by this line:

```
exchange_token(:code => params[:code])
```

I can't see this method in your documentation? The `merge!` method is obviously being caused inside this method somewhere - we need to know where it's being called, so we can fix it!

I can see one mention of `merge`, which I've queried above

---

**Update**

Thanks for posting the code!

I think `@mischa` is right - but I'll keep this code to show you what I'd look at..

I can only give an opinion, as I've never used this gem before -There are two calls to `merge!` in the gem code:

```
params.merge!(client_params)

@options.merge!(:access_token => response.access_token, :refresh_token => response.refresh_token)
```

I'd look at this:

**Params**

The params hash is populated locally like this:

```
params = if options_for_refresh_flow_present?
    {
      :grant_type => 'refresh_token',
      :refresh_token => refresh_token,
    }
  elsif options_for_credentials_flow_present?
    {
      :grant_type => 'password',
      :username => @options[:username],
      :password => @options[:password],
    }
  elsif options_for_code_flow_present?
    {
      :grant_type => 'authorization_code',
      :redirect_uri => @options[:redirect_uri],
      :code => @options[:code],
    }
  end
```

This could be the cause of the problem, as it is populated with `elsif` (not `else`). This means you have to make sure you're passing the right codes to the system

**@options**

`@options` is referenced but not declared

I imagine it's declared in another part of the gem code, meaning you need to make sure it's there. This will likely be set when the gem initializes (I.E when you set up the authentication between SC & your app)

If you've not got the `@options` set up correctly, it will probably mean you're not calling the gem correctly, hence the error.

Try `mischa`'s fix, and see if that cures the issue for you.

---

**Initializer**

Something to note - convention for including gems in your system is to use an `initializer`

If you set up an initializer which creates a new constant called SOUNDCLOUD, you can then reference that throughout your app (curing any errors you have here)

I can write some code for you on this if you want

Comment: `exchange_token` comes from the `SoundCloud` class, which is probably a standard library for communicating with SoundCloud.

Comment: Thanks for clarification - still it's causing the error somehow

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for your feedback. Regarding the options var, I sort of took that from an (old) example of the SoundCloud authentication flow for Ruby that I found on GitHub. I have, however, updated my post above with more context surrounding the error, including the affected line and the method it originates from in the SoundCloud gem that I'm using. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `params` is set based on three conditions (`if`, `elsif`, `elsif`) apparently all those conditions are `false` and thus `params` is `nil`. This still doesn't help much is finding the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes it does - if params is `nil` you got your error, which means you can then think about why params is not populated, which would have probably lead me to your answer evetually

Comment: So, I tried changing the instance variables to constants, but that didn't yield any changes in my code. I'm going to try the suggestion made by Uri below and let you guys know how it goes later on this evening. Thanks. Regarding the initializer, I completely forgot about that! I'll try adding it on my own, but if I have any more trouble, I would love your assistance in writing a proper instance method.

Comment: My answer was wrong. Sorry. Good luck finding the solution @RichSmith

Answer (score 0):

@RickPeck got very close I think, as the problem really lies in this code [excerpt](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby/blob/b98a87cb4806309130b1a63dcb3ab2048476c196/lib/soundcloud/client.rb#L110):

> ```
> params = if options_for_refresh_flow_present?
>     {
>       :grant_type => 'refresh_token',
>       :refresh_token => refresh_token,
>     }
>   elsif options_for_credentials_flow_present?
>     {
>       :grant_type => 'password',
>       :username => @options[:username],
>       :password => @options[:password],
>     }
>   elsif options_for_code_flow_present?
>     {
>       :grant_type => 'authorization_code',
>       :redirect_uri => @options[:redirect_uri],
>       :code => @options[:code],
>     }
>   end
> ```

`@options` *is* populated in the line `store_options(options)`. So the problem is that neither `options_for_refresh_flow_present?`, `options_for_credentials_flow_present?`, nor `options_for_code_flow_present?` return true.

The relevant option for your code is [code flow](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby/blob/b98a87cb4806309130b1a63dcb3ab2048476c196/lib/soundcloud/client.rb#L171):

> ```
> def options_for_code_flow_present?
>   !!(@options[:code] && @options[:redirect_uri])
> end
> ```

which expects `options` to have both `:code` *and* `:redirect_uri`. In your code you pass only `:code`. Add a `:redirect_uri` and you should be good to go.

What @Mischa suggests will probably fix that for you, as your `:redirect_uri` was `nil` when you set it...

Comment: Thanks, Uri! I'll try reworking this a bit this evening and let you know how it goes for me.