# trying to implement SoundCloud api having trouble finding access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, soundcloud, access-token

I have been able to have a user log in with soundcloud, but after they have logged in, I dont have access to their information, bc at this point I believe i need an access_token.  It is unclear to me where I would get this access token.  In my testing im just trying to access my own account

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController 
require 'soundcloud'
    def index

    end


    def new
        client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => "CLIENT_ID",
                        :client_secret => "CLIENT_SECRET",
                        :scope => "non-expiring",
                        :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/users/show')

        redirect_to client.authorize_url()
    end 

    def show 
        client = Soundcloud.new(:access_token => 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SHOULD_GO_HERE')
        puts client.get('/me').username
    end
end
```

not sure what other information I should provide the app is pretty thin, but any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have spent quite a bit of time combing through the soundcloud docs and have not really found my answer there ( its possible maybe its there and i just didnt understand it)...

This is the bit from the docs where it talks about accessing an account, it sats I should have the token after initial authentication, but again no mention of where the access token should come from or where I can find it.

SoundCloud docs

```
# create a client object with access token
client = Soundcloud.new(:access_token => 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN')

# print out the user's username
puts client.get('/me').username

# update the user's profile description
user = client.post('/me', :description => 'I am using the SoundCloud API!')
puts user.description
```

UPDATE 1 I have figured out where the access_token comes from, .. after the client grants access, then there is a code in the params after the redirect  and this :code is exchanged for an access_token, ..using this code

```
def new
        client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => "CLIENT_ID",
                        :client_secret => "CLIENT_SECRET",
                        :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/users/show')

        redirect_to client.authorize_url()

        code = params[:code]
    access_token = client.exchange_token(:code => code)
end
```

now I am getting an error saying "undefined method `merge!' for nil:NilClass"
this is the same scenario another guy posted about a few months ago here..

[Getting 'undefined method `merge!' when merging SoundCloud exchange token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646602/getting-undefined-method-merge-when-merging-soundcloud-exchange-token)

lots of discussion, but no clear answer.. would be great if someone could nudge me in the right direction.

its worth noting that in the URL after the redirect, I see an :access_token and also a :code, but I am unclear how to get those params to show up in my code in the correct places

UPDATE 2:  I was able to hack together an answer, but feel free to answer if you know of a better way.

```
    def new


        @client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => "CLIENT_ID",
                        :client_secret => "CLIENT_SECRET",
                        :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/users/show')

        redirect_to @client.authorize_url(:scope => "non-expiring")

    end 

    def show 
   @client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => "CLIENT_ID",
                        :client_secret => "CLIENT_SECRET",
                        :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/users/show')

   @code = params[:code]
   @access_token = @client.exchange_token(:code => @code)  
   @authed_client = Soundcloud.new(:access_token => @access_token)


    end
end
```

I am not totally sure, why this works and the way I had it earlier didnt, but in case you run into the same problem you can try it..